# Adding exceptions to laravel orm scopes

Tags: php, orm, laravel

I have a table called snippets. It contains in it, amnongst other fields, the following:

```
ID - autoincrement
TITLE -varchar(60)
PRETTY- varchar(60)
HTML - text
```

My snippet model is set up as you would expect:

```
class Snippet extends BaseModel
{

protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $rules = ['html' => 'required',
                'pretty' => 'required|unique'];

public function scopeFromPretty($query,$prettyUrl)
    {
        return $query->where('pretty', '=', $prettyUrl);
    }

}
```

This works fine if the $prettyUrl exists.

So for instance, the following line works fine, assuming there is a record with 'faq' in the pretty field.

```
$article = Snippet::fromPretty("faq")->first();
```

However, if the pretty url field doesn't exist, then $article will be empty.

Now, I could check for this in the controller, but, in my limited laravel experience, this feels wrong. I would instead like to check in the model, but don't see how I would do that.

I have tried the following:

```
public function scopeFromPretty($query,$prettyUrl)
    {
        $article = $query->where('pretty', '=', $prettyUrl);
            if ($article->count() == 0)
            {$article = $query->where('pretty', '=', "lost");}
        return $article;
    }
```

The aim here is to check to see if an article was found, and if it wasn't return an article which says "Your link was invalid. Please try again", or something similar.

However, this returns an empty result set (even though the "lost" Url exists in the table. At a guess I would say that the original where query is still in force, but I wouldn't know for sure.

I have a feeling that there must be a straightforward way to do this but that I am missing it, so any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using the repository pattern. It is very popular in the Laravel community. http://vimeo.com/53029232

> The aim here is to check to see if an article was found, and if it wasn't return an article which says "Your link was invalid. Please try again", or something similar.

I would also recommend throwing an exception rather than returning a row from the database. You could then catch the exception in your controller and render an alternative view. This is an example of what your code could look like.

SnippetRepositoryInterface.php

```
interface SnippetRepositoryInterface {

    /*
     * Gets snippets by pretty url.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     * @throws \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
     */
    public function getSnippetByPretty();
}
```

DbSnippetRepository.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class DbSnippetRepository implements SnippetRepositoryInteface {

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSnippetByPretty($url)
    {
        if (Snippet::fromPretty($url)->count())
        {
            return Snippet::fromPretty($url)->get();
        }

        throw new ModelNotFoundException(sprintf('The snippet for "%s" could not be found.', $url));
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for a very quick response. I am still at the butt-clenching stage of my laravel learning, and the above seems an awful lot of work for what I would have thought was a fairly straightforward (if elusive) task. What would happen, for instance, if instead of rendering a view, I wanted to just get the title from the pretty URL? And if the pretty URL was invalid, I just wanted the word "invalid"?  If I am not making sense let me know and I will expand my question.

Comment: I would recommend buying the "From Apprentice to Artisan" eBook. It is around $35 (depending on how much you want to donate) and it explains all the design patterns which you can use in Laravel to write really testable, reusable code. I would highly recommend it. https://leanpub.com/laravel

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be straightforward.

When I did my original scope query, the multiple where clauses were effectively being anded together.

Instead, I needed to change the second where clause to orWhere.

```
public function scopeFromPretty($query,$prettyUrl)
    {
        $article = $query->where('pretty', '=', $prettyUrl);
        if ($article->count() == 0)
        {$article = $query->orWhere('pretty', '=', "lost");}
        return $article;
    }
```

Note that I couldn't just do the following:

```
        return $query->where('pretty', '=', $prettyUrl);
                     ->orWhere('pretty', '=', "lost");}
```

If you do that method, and the prettyUrl happens to be returned after the lost url, then you will get the lost url.